# How rewrite Java generec's into Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, generics

I have java class and I need to rewrite it in kotlin. But I can't rewrite generics into it.

Java class:

```java
public abstract class AbstractFlagFilterFactory<T extends FlagFilter> extends FilterFactory {

    abstract Class<T> getFilterFlagType();

    abstract void processFlag(org.jooq.SelectQuery<?> query, T flag);
}
```

My Kotlin class

```kotlin
abstract class AbstractFlagFilterFactory<out FlagFilter> : FilterFactory {

   abstract fun getFilterFlagType(): Class<out ru.vtblife.realtyobject.domain.filters.FlagFilter>

   abstract fun processSetFlag(
        query: org.jooq.SelectQuery<...(1)>,
        flag: Class<out ru.vtblife.realtyobject.domain.filters.FlagFilter>
    )
}
```

Sign **(1)** I marked the my problem area by my opinion. But maybe the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: What do you mean "maybe the problem is somewhere else"? How are you not sure where the problem is when *you* are rewriting some code? What is the error message? As for (1), how about `org.jooq.SelectQuery<*>` or `org.jooq.SelectQuery<out Any?>`.

Comment: I meant that maybe I made a mistake in another line and the problem is actually there. For example, when defining a class. I don't know what right for `org.jooq.SelectQuery<?>` for kotlin. Compilator throws a message "Type expected" for empty `<>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin's `<out FlagFilter>` is *not* equivalent to Java's `<T extends FlagFilter>`. Using `out` at a generic declaration site makes the type covariant. This is called *declaration-site variance*, which is a feature that isn't even supported in Java.

The feature you want here is *generic upper bound*. The equivalent to Java's `<T extends FlagFilter>` is `<T: FlagFilter>`. This makes FlagFilter the upper bound of T.

The reason this is confusing is that Java overloads the `extends` word for both variance and upper bounds, and the meaning depends on the context. If you see a `? extends` or `? super`, it's covariance or contravariance, respectively. Otherwise, `extends` is for upper bound. It also doesn't help that the Java documentation avoids the word "variance" and instead calls covariance "upper-bounded wildcard" and contravariance "lower-bounded wildcard".

And in your function, you should use `<*>` in Kotlin as the equivalent of `<?>` in Java.

Comment: if I need val as `val setFlags: Map<Class<out FlagFilter>, FlagFilter>`, `Class<out FlagFilter>` would that be the wrong definition?

Comment: where `FlagFilter` is an interface, and `TypeFlagFilter` and `NumberFlagFilter` are classes that implement it. Will I be able to put such classes in `setFlags`?

Comment: That will work. Whether that's the right thing to do depends on how you're using the retrieved values. If it works without a compile error, you most likely did it correctly.